# A wedding anniversary or just an anniversary?

Tags: word-usage

Knowing the fact that an anniversary refers to the date on which a couple were married in a previous year, then do the word 'wedding' sound redundant in the self-made sentence bellow or using it sounds natural and it would be optional to be used in such this particular sentence:

> - Every year I buy my wife a trinket for our **wedding** anniversary.

Comment: Why do you think there is a fact? `Every year I buy my wife a trinket for our anniversary.` could also be the first date or the first time they get in contact...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, an anniversary is the day on which any event happened in a previous year (e.g., "Today is the 12th anniversary of Barack Obama's speech at the 2004 Democratic convention.") However, in your sentence, since you're talking about buying something for your wife, it's clear that you're referring to your wedding anniversary, so the word "wedding" is redundant (although not technically wrong).

Comment: i know couples that celebrate all sorts of anniversaries. First meeting, first date, first.... etc. For these people, **wedding** is not redundant.